# Prove that lim sin (1/x) as x-> 0 does not exist.

Tags: limits

Prove that lim sin (1/x) as x-> 0 does not exist.

Not really sure where to go with this, do I approach from both the right and left?

Comment: No, consider the sequences $x_n = \dfrac1{\pi n}$ and $x'_n = \dfrac1{\pi/2 + 2\pi n}$.

Comment: Why to ask again the same question you did 7 hours ago? You also received there three answers, one of which is just the same as Njguliev's comment!

Comment: I did not notice this. Otherwise, I would not have answered. I am surprised that @Sade basically just gave the same answer twice. Care to explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try to find two sequences $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to 0$ such that, for instance, $\sin(1/x_n)=1$ and $\sin(1/y_n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use Negation of sequential criterion for existance of limit.